# write Legacy views in Standard SQL format

Tags: google-bigquery

I wish to update my big query table :

```
FROM [myProject.Mydataset.ga_sessions_20171129]
```

I can update it to a standard SQL format:

```
 FROM `myProject.Mydataset.ga_sessions_20171129`
```

ga_sessions_20171129 is my table id and the last part of its name shows the last date that the table is updated, so the next table for the next day will be 20171130

How do I write something like that?

```
from `ga_sessions_*` where _TABLE_SUFFIX=TODAY
```

That updates the date every day to today's date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. However, when I want to save the view, I got this error `Failed to save view. Views cannot be queried through prefix. Partial list of the matched views are:...` Do you know what the issue is?

Comment: make sure you enabled Standard SQL. I was able to save view and then use it in query

Comment: wanted to mention - you cannot use view written in Standard SQL within the query written in Legacy SQL!! and vice versa!

Comment: That's right. The view is originally written in Legacy SQL and I tried to write it in Standard SQL. I enabled Standard SQL and still cannot save the view. I'll try to find the issue and might come back here. thanks for your help

Comment: It sounds like the issue is that the `*` matches the name of a view. Even if the intent is to filter out this name, it cannot match in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, @Elliott Brossard, it seems you're correct. I noticed we have some views on this name `ga_sessions_S_ 20171129` and probably it caused some confusion. Do you have any idea how we can help this problem?

Comment: One idea is to make the wildcard more specific. For example, try making it be `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20*` and then using `_TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())` (note the lowercase `y` in the `FORMAT_DATE`).

Comment: Thanks for you help Elliott, but even that one didn't work and we see the same error.

Comment: thanks, @MikhailBerlyant, I accepted your answer and will send another question shortly.

Comment: sure. if not yet - please also consider voting answers up. It is important on SO. This increase your own reputation score and at the same time you keep us motivated to answer your next questions :o) please consider!

Comment: Hi Mikhail, this one is already done and I upvoted your answer when you posted it, the new question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563168/writing-legacy-views-in-standard-sql-format-in-bigquery